# Python string extraction

Tags: python

In the following string how to get the id after the directory media and after getting the id ignore the rest of the string to read only the id numbers

```
id_arr= ["/opt/media/12/htmls","/opt/media/24/htmls","/opt/media/26/htmls","/opt/media/56/htmls"]
```

The output should be 12 24 26 56

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the strings always look the way you said, try

```
ids = [int(s.split("/")[3]) for s in id_arr]
```

Comment: Maybe use `os.path.sep` instead of a plain `/`, just in case?

Comment: Not sure if these are paths or parts of URLs.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> myre = re.compile("^.*/media/(\d+)")
>>> for item in id_arr:
...     print (myre.search(item).group(1))
...
12
24
26
56
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Yeah, regexes are bit overkill, but they satisfy the requirement that we're extracting the numerical ID after the `media` directory. No other solution considers the possibility that it might not be the third field (not even Puller's, since it assumes the prefix is `/opt/media`).

Answer (score 0):

[x.split('/')[3] for x in id_arr]

Answer (score 0):

```
parts = "/opt/media/12/htmls","/opt/media/24/htmls","/opt/media/26/htmls","/opt/media/56/htmls"
for str in parts:
    print str.split("/")[3]
```

EDIT: unuseful rpartition() removed

Answer (score 0):

The correct way probably involves some clever use of the `os.path` module, but for the input given, just use a regex for `media\/([0-9]+)` and extract the first group.